# CH type breaker clip compatibility issue

Tags: circuit-breaker

My sub-panel is a type CH panel. I fried a 15A breaker and need to replace it.

I picked up a replacement Eaton CH type breaker. The clamps on the bus/load bar work perfectly, but the clips on the other end are different.

The older breaker has metal clips with a gap and the new one has a plastic clip without a gap such that it won’t sit well on the panel. The measurements of the new breaker are almost the same as old - the clips are in almost identical position.

I can’t find any new CH type breakers with a similar clip as the old one. Do I cut the bit out plastic out on the new breaker or is there something else I could do ?

P.S. I just realized that the new breaker is a CHF115.
And it looks like what I need is a CH115

Here are some pics. The one on left is old breaker with metal clip. The right breaker is new.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like there’s a bunch of CH115 with metal feet/clips on eBay. Used/refurbished. I’m not sure how comfortable I am with used breakers. I’ll check the local electrical supply store when they open Monday.

Comment: Talk to Eaton.  The breakers are under warranty (well they are if they have a tan handle.  When the warranty expires, the handle turns black.)

Comment: This sub panel was installed in 1988 when previous owner built the addition to the house. Does the limited warranty really work after 35 years ? The panel box is labeled CH16BB and it’s a CTL type panel. There seem to a few sellers on eBay that claim to be selling new breakers - some call it ‘Metal Foot Full Notch’ and others ‘Metal Foot Half Notch’ - both look the same. I imagine other houses of the same era in the area might have the same panel type which makes me think local stores might have some old stock.

Comment: Yes, lifetime warranty on CH. China has been known to counterfeit our breakers, so I would not trust anything bought on any of the flea market sites, double especially Amazon Marketplace, which are 95% of Amazon listings these days.  Really [Amazon's own inventory is tainted too due to commingling](https://www.redpoints.com/blog/amazon-commingled-inventory-management/).  So stick to walking into a reputable shop and taking it off a shelf - home store or electrical supply house. Or from Eaton direct by mail in the case of a warranty item.

Comment: Congratulations on recognizing that breakers aren't universally compatible and making sure that you got a proper replacement breaker that is correct for your panel.  Too often on this group I see people just blindly picking up whatever breaker is cheapest and not paying attention to what breaker(s) are legal for the specific panel.

Answer (score 3):

I was not hooking the new breaker correctly. The new style breaker is a little wider and has to be hooked properly by the foot to the lip in the panel board. It works perfectly. As per EATON, they stopped making the old metal foot breakers a year ago. My local electrical supply shop didn’t have any of the old one but they showed me how the plastic foot hooks onto the panel board.

The new style breaker with plastic foot CHF115 works fine with the older board that I have.