# Lab inc. list circuit breaker

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

I need to replace a 15amp breaker. I am so new I think it's a single pole because there is only one switch.
But I can't find any with the hooks at the bottom. What can I use?
I read some stuff about other brands that are bad but have the same bus, or home structure?
Any help to guide me to a breaker I can use?  Can I go up to 20amp?

[image]

Comment: Please show us other sides of the breaker. Also, no, you cannot upgrade to a 20 amp breaker unless you can verify that **all** of the wiring on the circuit is at least 12 gauge. You most likely have 14 gauge on a 15 amp circuit.

Comment: The "UND LAB INC" on that label is not the brand of circuit breaker. The label is telling you that it's "Listed" with the "Underwriters Laboratory" (aka UL).

Comment: Also provide pictures of the panel you propose to put this into, particularly its internal labeling and the bus structure.

Comment: In addition, this might be enlightening: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/131728/18078

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CH type breaker clip compatibility issue](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/287617/ch-type-breaker-clip-compatibility-issue)

Answer (score 6):

That appears to be an **Eaton CH 115** breaker, based on a picture that makes no attempt to show that. **Und. Lab Inc.** is the *testing laboratory* that verifies its suitability for use, not the *maker*.

However, to be sure you get the right breaker, check the label on the panel you are putting it into. *If someone put the wrong breaker into the panel in the past, and that's why it failed, repeating their mistake would be the wrong solution.*

[This question and answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/287617/18078) indicate that Eaton has moved to a plastic clip for that type of breaker, so new ones won't look exactly like old ones with the metal clip.

Comment: CH superfan here. This answer is correct. The dead giveaway is the breaker lever, colored Sandalwood.   When the warranty expires, it turns black.  (lifetime warranty).